# Does the CR of a bone devil include the potential of summoning 2d6 spined devils?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, encounter-design

The [Bone Devil](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Bone%20Devil#content), when using the Devil Summoning Variant, has the ability to attempt to *Summon Devil* (1/Day).

Having a read through the appropriate page on [themonstersknow.com](http://themonstersknow.com/devil-tactics-lesser-devils/) it discusses the idea that it makes the most sense to attempt this on turn 1.

This means we have a scenario were the Bone Devil succeeds on the summoning and now has (on average) 7 spined devils fighting with them.

How does this effect the encounter difficulty? Is it as simple as going from a 5,000 XP encounter to a 8,150 XP encounter (adjusted 16,300)?

The CR level given to the Bone Devil, does this include this scenario or is it seperate?

Comment: [Same question for a different monster.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/89555/15469)

Comment: The answer to that question even addresses Devil Summoning explicitly.