# Spells attacks on Wizard Spells and saving throws

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard

Sorry for the noob question but i am still learning
So far i have been a level 3 wizard in one of the campaigns. Every time i use a damaging spell the DM tells me to roll for attack spell (to see if hit or not). Now as i was reading about what my spells do, some say to roll for a spell attack and some do not, those who do not say to roll, do they hit?

Example: Fire bolt Vs Poison Spray, both are cantrip wizard spells

Comment: Of course, it's possible your DM's making use of a [Players Make All Rolls](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/UA5_VariantRules.pdf) scheme.... But then see http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/69064/23970.

Answer (score 4):

You do exactly as the spell says. When it says you need to make an attack roll, then you do. If it says the target can make a saving throw to avoid damage, then it does.

It is highly unlikely, that a spell comes without one or the other (but they exist, Magic Missile for example). It is also highly unlikely that a spell has *both*, an attack roll *and* a saving throw.

The only answer I can give you is this: **read the spell description**.

Answer (score 4):

If not explicitly stated otherwise, you do not have to roll to hit.

Spells such as poison spray, fireball, and lightning bolt all require a saving throw to deal full damage, not an attack roll. This causes them to always be able to deal at least partial damage. That is what your wizard save DC is for.

Frost Ray would require an attack roll, for instance, because it explicitly calls for such a roll. If it hits, you do damage. If it misses, you do none. That is the difference