# Are there guidelines for homebrewed content?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, class, gm-preparation

I am going to be a first-time DM in the near future, and one of the players wants to run a homebrewed class that sounds pretty exciting. I'm eager to include the class, but some searching only turned up homebrewing guidelines for [dnd-3.5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e).

Are there official [dnd-5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) guidelines for homebrew content that exist outside what's already provided in the DMG (official errata etc.) and where might I be able to find them?

Comment: Can you give us an idea of *why* you're looking for other sources outside what's in the DMG? Is what's in the DMG insufficient for the task?

Comment: @PurpleMonkey The DMG doesn't cover everything. I'm more looking for additional official sources to use in conjunction with the DMG. More resources are better after all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Forewarning:*** While the following suggested material is published by WotC, it should be noted that the contents presented in these articles may only be, effectively, playtest material. It may not been fully refined and *may* cause unexpected balance issues. [It's even been contested as *"official"* material](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/84837/14878).

---

## Yes, they are in the Unearthed Arcana.

One of the best examples of this is found in the [first feats UA](https://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/UA-Feats-V1.pdf). In this installment, you are given examples with explanations for why each one is bad or good. You can directly use this advice to make your own homebrewed feats.

A less successful UA comes in their [Modifying Class](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/modifying-classes) installment. They give a good rationale for what to look out for when modifying classes, and what the designers intended for each class to do. It fails in immediately presenting examples that don't follow its own advice (in particular, the Favored Soul).

A ready-made version of homebrew can be found in the [variant rules](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/UA5_VariantRules.pdf) installment. They give you rules for Players Make All the Rolls ([beware: the math is incorrect here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/69064/23064)), Vitality, Custom Alignments.

You also have a UA installment of what players can do during their [downtime](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UA_Downtime.pdf). These are alternative rules you can put into your game which lend the same effect of "homebrew made for you."

Also, there is the UA on [encounter building](http://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/Encounter_Building.pdf). While there are already rules for the DMG with regards to building monsters, this tells you how to make encounters/battles instead.

Finally, there is the UA installment of [Traps](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/0227_UATraps.pdf), which instructs you how to make simple and complex traps, how to run them (even using Initiative to do so), why to use them, as well as a lot of premade traps you can readily insert into your games. It goes into a level of detail that the DMG does not have.

Comment: Markov, I've added a bit of a cautionary note at the top of this answer. Please review it and if you (or even another user) feel it inappropriate or that it changes the tone of your answer, or even if you simply disagree with it, please feel free to roll it back or edit it further.