# Balance implications of these output to input luck change house rules?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, balance, house-rules, statistics

### What classes and approaches are helped and/or hindered by this set of house rules?

For an upcoming DnD 5e campaign I am considering two house rules, both of which substantially effect one another. The implications are far reaching and complex enough I am having trouble deciding what classes, techniques, and playstyles come out ahead or behind.

### Rule 1: Players Roll Rule

- When a PC is attacked, they roll a defense and add ac bonus vs a static
  attack (calculated as attack bonus +10)
- When a PC casts a save spell
  on an NPC they roll, and add the DC bonus (static save for npc is
  calculated as save+12)

### Rule 2: Deck Play in Combat

- Use a 52 card deck (without Jokers) instead of a D20 during combat rounds.

  - When initiative is rolled in combat draw 10 cards.
  - When a D20 would be rolled as part of an action (not a free action) instead you must play a card from your hand.
  - Red number cards are listed value
  - Black number cards are listed value plus 10
  - Aces are 1 (1 if red, 11 if black)
  - Royals are top of your discard minus a value. K=D-1, Q=D-2, J=D-3

    - If the top card of the discard is a royal or the discard is empty, the royal is =2
    - When the last card is played from your hand, draw back up to ten
  - When the last card is drawn from your deck, shuffle in the discard.
- Adv and Disadv

  - Advantage is "play 1 card from your hand, and the top card of the deck, take the higher result"
  - Disadvantage is "play 1 card from your hand, and the top card of the deck, take the lower result"
- You may take a full round action to discard your entire hand and draw up to ten.

### NOTES

The title of this campaign, as pitched to the players, is **"An extremely house rule heavy and experimental campaign"** so they at least know what they're in for. ^_^

Rule tweaks and alternatives sound conversationally fun, but are not quite answers.

The motivation here is to turn some output random into input random, inspired by this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwI5b-wRLic

This is intended to embrace the "figure out the enemies' ac/hp/attack value" aspect of some combat.

Comment: I think you need to split this into two separate questions. They are fundamentally different and trying to combine into two limits our ability to answer a specific question.

Comment: Some questions regarding your first houserule: Can monster still get critical hits/misses? What is an "AC bonus"? Is this just Dexterity, but then what happens to things like the Monk and Barbarian Unarmored Defense features, the *barkskin* and *mage armor* spells, and other such changes to AC? Would this change only apply to the PC rolls, while monsters will still use the regular rules?

Comment: I can see how Rule 2 relates to input vs output randomness, but not Rule 1. When splitting the question, I think you should maybe clarify the design intent of Rule 1?

Comment: It would probably do well to describe what it means to turn output random into input random more concisely than a 20 minute video as well, these aren't particularly well known or used terms

Comment: [How do I convert saving throws into defences](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/31471/23970) is strongly related to, if not a dupe target for, your first half. ([Players Make All Rolls...](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/69064/23970) covers it, too.)

Comment: For pt. 2: does each player have their own deck/discard, or is the whole party working off of one deck?